# WebGL fragment shader not branching correctly on if statement

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm working on a WebGL program which implements shadow mapping. After computing the depth values at each fragment, I have an if statement at the end which computes the lighting based on whether the fragment is in a shadow or not.

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(calcLighting(light0, eye_dir, eye_dir_norm, normal), 1);
if (light_tex_coord.z - depth <= 0.0) {
  gl_FragColor += vec4
      ( calcLighting(light1, eye_dir, eye_dir_norm, normal)
      , 0.0
      );
}
```

[image: Shadows not being correctly computed, branch never taken]

where `depth` is the depth of the shadow map and `light_tex_coord` is the fragment's position in the scene space of `light1`. `light1` is a point light rotating around the model, and `light0` is a point light statically positioned at the camera.

The issue here is that the if branch is never taken, so the scene only has `light0` applied to it. I've checked that `depth`, `light_tex_coord`, and `calculateLighting` work correctly.

Here's the strange thing, though, replacing the above with the following code:

```
if (light_tex_coord.z - depth <= 0.0) {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
} else {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

[image: Shadowed fragments correctly computed and drawn as red and green]

Causes shadowed areas to be correctly drawn in red, and unshadowed to be drawn in green. That is, the branch is correctly evaluated. Replacing it with this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(calcLighting(light0, eye_dir, eye_dir_norm, normal), 1);
gl_FragColor += vec4
    ( calcLighting(light1, eye_dir, eye_dir_norm, normal)
    , 0.0
    );
```

[image: Lighting computed without shadows]

Causes lighting to be correctly computed (sans shadows, though). It seems that when I call the more expensive calcLighting function in the if statement, it doesn't even bother taking it.

Further, I've tried applying the lighting in several ways including using the `clamp` function; always doing the addition and using a terinary operator to multiply the second `calcLighting` call by 1 or 0, and arranging my if statement in different ways. Nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing about how branching works in webgl?

Comment: Have you tried accumulating the color to a separate `vec4` variable and **only** assigning `gl_FragColor` the value of this other variable one time. Writing to `gl_FragColor` multiple times in a shader is supposed to be supported as is reading the value of it (which is necessary to implement `+=`) but by all accounts this issue seems to be related to one or both of these actions given your control flow.

Comment: I tried replacing all instances of `gl_FragColor` in the above snippets with an accumulator `vec4 acc;`. I only assigned at the end of the shader with `gl_FragColor = acc;` No change in any of the above cases.

Comment: Could you provide the entire fs code?
Also, would it make any difference if you change code to `gl_FragColor += vec4( calcLight(..), 1.0 )`? [note 1.0 alpha value]

Comment: Changing the alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 has no effect. It's a large chunk of code, so I put it on pastebin. vertex shader: http://pastebin.com/XLYSwvL7 fragment shader: http://pastebin.com/bYdvuRjj The snippet in question is from the bottom of the fragment shader.

Comment: Since this is WebGL, it would be helpful if you can make a page where we can try this out / change stuff if we manage to reproduce the error. It kind of seems like a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the WebGl context does not support depth. Then expressions using it would be ignored.

You can check this with getContextAttributes()

Comment: In my javascript code, I check for the depth extension, and if it doesn't exist, then I write the depth values to the color buffer. In any case, the browsers I've tested this on support the depth extension.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the branch, have you considered something really radical like this:

```
gl_FragColor += vec4 (
    calcLighting(light1, eye_dir, eye_dir_norm, normal)
    , 0.0
    ) * abs (min (sign (light_tex_coord.z - depth), 0.0));
```

It is not the prettiest solution in the world, but it just might get you something more along the lines of what you are looking for. It basically takes your `light_tex_coord.z - depth <= 0.0` conditional expression and makes it into a nice floating-point **0.0** or **1.0** that you can multiply the lighting by to either *keep* or *discard* the branch result. Kind of the way shaders ***used*** to work before dynamic flow control was introduced.

Comment: It's a neat idea, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is 2 years old but here's my 2 cents:

I had a similar problem and found an page on the Internet with a discussion containing the following sentence :

> [...] (unless you do crazy stuff like image writes inside conditional
>   blocks). [...]

So I tried to put the pixel color in a temporary variable

```
vec4 col;
```

local to main(), in the "if" statements I modify only col, and I set the pixel color only at the very end:

```
gl_FragColor = col;
```

This solved my problem. Of course it may require annoying additionnal programming to let the flow reach that last line in every situation.